# Read JSONP and pass it to PHP ajax Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am currently in process of developing a search script which is based on an JSONP API.
I got this working so far (server side, PHP) but I am not required to retrieve the JSONP information client side (JQUERY).

I have done some research but not found a decent solution for this.
I would like to retrieve the Data (can be up to 500 records) via JQUERY (i.e. with getJSON() or any other way) and somehow pass it to my AJAX/PHP file which will do the necessary filtering and displaying.
Is this something what is easily achievable?

So far I am using the following and it is working fine (server side):

```
$car_list = file_get_contents($json_url);
$car_list = json_decode($car_list,true);
$car_meta = $car_list['meta'];
$car_list = $car_list['data'];
```

The first line is what I would like JQuery to do and continue with PHP from there onwards.

I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: So let me get this straight. You're passing JSON data to your php file and process it in order to display a new result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correct you want to get information with jQuery and send it to server, yes? If so why do you need it, why not from server? 
Anyway you can do 2 requests. First to jsonp API and in callback you can send it to server, but it looks a little bit strange. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - ajax function description. You need to setup dataType as jsonp, and setup callback with ajax to your server.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is a requirement by the API supplier (apparently server to server is not allowed and it has to run client side, dont really know why).

Do you, by any chance, got a working sample I can work with? I am not 100% familiar with all aspects of jquery and wonder if you could point me in the correct direction on this?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried the following and I can see the content in firebug.
However, I am not sure how I can pass it to my php script via the call back.

$.ajax({
 url: "xxx",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(results){
  console.log(results);
 }
});

Comment: sorry pressed enter for new line... Something like this: `function jsopCallback(params){ $.ajax({data:data, type: 'post', url: 'Your_url', success: function(response){//your code ghere}, error(){} }); } $.ajax({url:'url to jsonp', data: 'data to jsonp', dataType: 'jsonp', jsonpCallback: jsopCallback});` Sorry for formatting i am new here...

Comment: Jsonp result goes to callback you specify in jsonpCallback. And there you can do sometnihg with result and send it to your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I continued in the meantime and think I am nearly there.
The last thing missing now is how I can "load" the result of the AJAX file into the page 
this is what I got.
$.ajax({
 url: "xxx",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(results){
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'ajax/search-list.php',
   data: results,
   dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
 }
});

the ajax page contains a list which I would like to load into a div with a unique ID.
I did similar in the past using "load()" but not in combination with post(). Could you quickly help on this?

Comment: I fixed the issue now by removing "dataType" from the callback.

thanks a lot for your help